# DB is iso-8859-1, using utf8_encode characters get converted wrong

Tags: php, ajax, database, unicode, character-encoding

My DB uses ISO-8859-1 and I fetch data via `sqlsrv_query`. There are some characters like `“` and after fetching the data I use `utf8_encode()` function.

Then I echo send the data back to the Ajax Request with this setting:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($Data);
```

I catch the data via responseJSON and everything works fine, but here is an example of wrong encoding:

```
{"Products":{"1":{"ProductID":"1","Name":"Testproduct\u0084Foobar\u0093"}}}
```

With `\u0093` should be `“` but it isn't and its has the wrong Unicode it should be `\u201C` or doesn't even gets split into Unicode.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO 8859-1 does not include curved quote characters such as `“`; as can be [seen on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), character `0x93` is undefined, reserved for use as a control character.

However, when people specify ISO 8859-1, they often actually mean [Windows codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which replaces this reserved block with additional characters, including curved quotes. `0x93` is indeed `“` in Windows-1252, so it's reasonable to assume that that is what your database is actually configured for.

Since `utf8_encode` only handles ISO 8859-1, you therefore need to use a different function to convert to a Unicode encoding. There are two such functions bundled with the standard PHP distribution, from different extensions:

- [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) - something like `$utf8_string = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $db_string);`
- [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) - something like `$utf8_string = mb_convert_encoding($db_string, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');`

Comment: Thank you so much! Damn i thought i will never get this to work but it really wasn't ISO 8859-1 but Windows 1252...